# Enabling relative Tracking mode on wacom tablet - Ubuntu 18

Tags: tablet, wacom

I'm user of Ubuntu 18.04.04. Having trouble to make my -one wacom- tablet work. I followed the next instruction:

`sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04`

Now, works and its detected  properly. BUT selecting the relative tracking mode doesn't change the absolute tracking mode.

What I have to do?

UPDATE:
I Found that could be possible through xsetwacom set "device name" Mode "Absolute"

To tried that solution I put on terminal
`xsetwacom --list devices`

and got: xsetwacom don't found, then tried
`sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-wacom`

suggested by the terminal message and got:

```
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom: Depends: xserver-xorg-core (> = 2: 1.18.99.901)
E: The problems could not be corrected, you have retained broken packages.
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to figure out the ID of your Wacom Stylus. You can see the IDs of all your devices with

```bsh
xsetwacom --list devices
```

Then use that ID to set the `Mode` to `Relative` for your stylus:

```bsh
xsetwacom ---set $STYLUS_ID Mode "Relative"
```

And here's a one-liner that does all that for you:

```bsh
STYLUS_ID=$(xinput list | grep Wacom | grep stylus | sed -e 's/.*id=\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g') &&
  xsetwacom ---set $STYLUS_ID Mode "Relative"
```